# How to write code in another window of the same namespace in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have done this in the C# IDE. I have just created two enums. My 2nd enum which is a list of car makers in the world is unduly long. For convenience I would like to keep car makers separate. How to proceed with keeping it separate in another code window? I don't know how to create another window with the same namespace for this purpose where I can write this enum and still be able to access it from button1_Click event on form1. I raise this basic question because although I do a lot of data processing with elementary c# techniques, I always write everything on the same code window. This affects readability of my programmes. Could anyone advise me? Thanks.

```
namespace Class_Learning
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        enum colour
        {
            Red,
            Orange,
            Violet,
            Blue,
            Green,
            Black,
            Silver,
            White
        };
        enum carMake
        {
            //No space between words. Hence in some cases underscores
            Acura,
            Alfa_Romeo,
            Aston_Martin,
            Audi,
            Bentley,
            BMW,
            And_so_on____
        };
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can always add a additional window to form by adding new element in the solution explorer. to use any other namespace you need to use "using" statement i would recommend reading basics

Comment: An enum is the wrong thing to use here. Adding or removing a manufacturer requires a code change,  use a `Manufacturer` class and load them from a resource.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about creating a new class Manufacturer  and loading it from a resource.

Comment: This is the advice that help learners to understand things better. Thanks.. @Ron Beyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another file, move the enums out of your class, and make them `public` so they're accessible to your original class.

```
namespace Class_Learning
{
    public enum colour
        {
            Red,
            Orange,
            Violet,
            Blue,
            Green,
            Black,
            Silver,
            White
        };

    public enum carMake
        {
            //No space between words. Hence in some cases underscores
            Acura,
            Alfa_Romeo,
            Aston_Martin,
            Audi,
            Bentley,
            BMW,
        };
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Grant Winney and sumeet kumar @Grant Winney

Answer (score 0):

It took me pretty much time to understand. So I am detailing the procedure for people like me who have missed fundamentals.

1. From the menu Project click on Add New Item.
2. Select Code File and click on Add.
3. You will get an blank window.
4. When you use the same namespace, it is not necessary that the using statement be there in this file.
5. Write the code as detailed above by Grant Winney.

When referring to the enum in Form1 code, refer with namespace.enumname.enumelement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pure code file by right click the project and add a new class. You will have a class definition in the same namespace but in another .cs file. You can just remove the class and write your enum just as another post said.

Comment: I think you have suggested and the blank window and then coding there leads to the same result.. @bin3377